# using Arrow keys to navigate around a console app

Tags: objective-c, console-application, arrow-keys

Im learning Objective C by creating small console games in Xcode. I'm currently making a kind of battle ships grid game. Instead of the player inputing coordinates via scanF is there a way I can implement the use of arrows keys ? I've checked apple docs but I cannot find any class methods.

This is my code I want the player to navigate around:

```
NSMutableArray *theBoard = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
for (int i = 1; i < 101; i++) {
    [theBoard addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02d",i]];
}

// this prints the board to console
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    NSLog(@"     %@",[[theBoard subarrayWithRange:NSMakeRange(0+(i*10) , 10)]componentsJoinedByString:@"  "]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Mac OS X includes [Ncurses](http://www.gnu.org/s/ncurses/), which is a useful library for creating console-based UIs.